# Apache WSGI Python - отдельный WSGIPythonHome для virthost'a

Tags: python, virtualenv, wsgi, apache, django

Хотелось бы сделать 2 сайта разных пользователей с использованием различных окружений python, установленных с использованием virtualenv. То есть, пользователь ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ1 имеет сайт САЙТ1, ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ2 имеет САЙТ2. У каждого пользователя своя python-среда, установленная через virtualenv, к чужой среде пользователь доступа не имеет.

При попытке создания 2-х VirtualHost'ов, естественно, один из WSGIPythonHome'ов перекрывается, так как они задаются уровнем выше.

В общем, вопрос: есть ли какой-нибудь способ использовать apache с wsgi для разных пользователей, каждый из которых имеет своё окружение python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, проблема не решается обычными способами. Как вариант - использовать nginx + uwsgi.

Решено: перешел на nginx + uwsgi, всем доволен.